# Where do we ask for best translation of a passage?

Tags: discussion

Should that happen here or at Biblical Hermeneutics?

Say, "This passage is important to me, and I think its more literal translation of *blah, blah* would help smooth over some historical controversies, etc....."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translation is definitely the purview of Hermeneutics.

You can ask about interpretation here, but it should be in the context of a doctrine or denomination. We are pretty relativistic here where you may get a more truth based answer over there.

Answer (score 10):

I'm glad you asked and I'm glad wax eagle answered first. `;-)`

If you want a good answer on [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), it will help to ask a good question.  Here are some hints:

- Don't use [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), which is deprecated on BH.SE. Rather tag with the source language ([hebrew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [greek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), or [aramaic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic)) and the book of the Bible the passage comes from.
- Define what your translation question is clearly. The terms "best translation" or even "literal translation" are not very useful without qualification. Translation is at least as much [an art](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/491/55) as a science and there are many possible goals. Be sure to explain which goals are important to your question.
- When all the mainstream translations agree on a passage, there probably isn't much of a question about it. More productive are questions about why two or more professional translations materially disagree on a passage.
- Please take a moment to include the text of the passage in a `blockquote` with citations and a link rather than just listing a verse references. (This goes for all questions about specific Bible passages on any Stack Exchange site where such questions are on topic.)
- Avoid including any doctrinal elements in your question. Assume that the person answering your question is an atheist (though most answers are from Christians and Jews as it turns out).
- While not necessary, it can help to do some research to discover the original Greek or Hebrew wording. I find the [NET Bible](https://net.bible.org/) website ([classic edition](http://classic.net.bible.org/bible.php)) invaluable for this purpose. [The Blue Letter Bible](http://www.blueletterbible.org/) is a worthy alternative if you care about copying the original script.

We are always looking for more insightful translation questions!